# Create dictionary from table using hash object

Tags: hash, sas

I'm sure it's an easy task, but I'm still neophyte at SAS, so I have some problems :(.

Consider, I have some data set `Table` with column `Column $24` (length is important). And I want to create a data set `HashTable` with only one column `Key $11`, where `Key` consists of those unique values of `Column`, which  length equals 11.
So, I'm trying to use a hash object, but I feel I'm doing something wrong :).

```
data _null_;
    length Key $11;
    set Table end = _end;
    if _N_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h();
        h.defineKey('Key');
        h.defineDone();
    end;
    if length(Column) = 11 then
        rc = h.add(Key: Column);
    if _end then
        rc = h.output(dataset: 'HashTable');
run;
```

When I submit program I get errors:

```
7904    rc = h.add(Key: Column);
ERROR: Incorrect number of data entries specified at line 7904 column 14.
ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mistake was stupid, as I expected:)

The right code (I hope):

```
data _null_;
    length Key $11;
    set Table end = _end;
    if _N_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h();
        h.defineKey('Key');
        h.defineDone();
    end;
    if length(Column) = 11 then do;
        Key = Column;
        rc = h.add();
    end;
    if _end then
        rc = h.output(dataset: 'HashTable');
run;
```

Comment: Your rc=h.add(); statement will be executed unconditionally. You probably want to a add a do/end block to make it conditional on length(column).

Comment: Ops, again) Pythonic style)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been identified by Paul Dorfman in 2007 on SAS-L,  [Paul Dorfman on Hash error](https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0709a&L=SAS-L&P=58710)

Simply put, ADD() method is expecting either both 'key' and 'data' or none (which implies both). The following also works, even you 'data' hasn't been defined explicitly.

```
 data _null_ ;
length key $ 5;
  set sashelp.shoes end = _end ;
  if _N_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash h() ;
    h.defineKey('key') ;
    h.defineDone() ;
  end ;
  if length(Subsidiary)=5 then rc=h.add(key:subsidiary, data:Subsidiary) ;
  if _end then h.output(dataset: 'HashTable') ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't know this stuff about add() method. But using fake "data: " parameter to avoid this error is not a good way.

Comment: Just FYI, I forgot mentioning that REPLACE() method is the same in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty good to me.  The one mistake I notice is that your statements:

```
if length(Column) = 11 then;
    rc = h.add(Key: Column);
if _end then;
    rc = h.output(dataset: 'HashTable');
```

have an extra semicolon.  There should be no semicolon after the `then`.  As written, the h.add and h.output are executed unconditionally.

Here is an example using sashelp.shoes along the lines of your examole:

```
data _null_ ;
  set sashelp.shoes end = _end ;
  if _N_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash h() ;
    h.defineKey('Subsidiary') ;
    h.defineDone() ;
  end ;
  if length(Subsidiary)=5 then rc=h.add() ;

  if _end then h.output(dataset: 'HashTable') ;
run ;
```

Which returns:

```
115  data _null_ ;
116    set HashTable ;
117    put (_all_)(=) ;
118  run ;

Subsidiary=Tokyo
Subsidiary=Cairo
Subsidiary=Paris
Subsidiary=Seoul
Subsidiary=Dubai
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set WORK.HASHTABLE.
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, you're right about semicolons:). But I have other errors (I updated my answer, check it). Your code logic is a little bit different from mine, I guess that is why it works)